# angular cli update issue on local folder

Tags: angular-cli

After updating angular cli as mention on github

```
Global package:

npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Local project package:

rm -rf node_modules dist # use rmdir on Windows
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
ng update
```

> Running ng update will check for changes in all the auto-generated
>   files created by ng new and allow you to update yours. You are offered
>   four choices for each changed file: y (overwrite), n (don't
>   overwrite), d (show diff between your file and the updated file) and h
>   (help).

**when i do ng update** ???

```
demo@VSS-DT0094:~/Desktop/project-dev/client$ ng update
installing ng2
? Overwrite README.md? (yndH) y
>> Yes, overwrite
```

what to do next if i press Enter

it comes like this

```
demo@VSS-DT0094:~/Desktop/project-dev/client$
```

and doing again ng update

same result show

> demo@VSS-DT0094:~/Desktop/project-dev/client$ ng update installing ng2
>   ? Overwrite README.md? (yndH) y

Comment: I have the same issue, it is a known bug, they talk about it here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4584 No solution for it yet other than wait for them to fix it